# issue in decoding deflate encoded server response in uiwebview via jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ios, ajax, html, hybrid-mobile-app

Our’s is a hybrid app(ios uiwebview wrapper with `html5`,`jquery` and `css3`) currently using Ajax calls for web services handling. The backend , Siebel server sends the response data encoded using `deflate` http compression technique. But all modern webkit and webkit based browsers discontinued the support for deflate decoding and is hence unable to handle the response as it is failing the decoding. This issue happens in webkit of iOS version 7 onwards .If we are able to set a parameter `Accept-Encoding` header programmatically in the ajax call request to something other than deflate (say gzip) it may solve the prob.
But via jQuery Ajax, when we try to set this header in request via `javascript` file loaded from a web server it refuses the same saying - `refuse to set unsafe header Accept-Encoding` . Because of this server sends the deflate encoded data and hence handling fails at client side with Ajax returning Error(0).

Can you please suggest any alternative approach so that native `uiwebview` is able to decode the deflate encoded data from the server?